# Python AttributeError instance has no attribute

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I'm getting the following error:-

```
AttributeError: PageOne instance has no attribute 'scann'
```

I'm trying to run a bash script (runfocus).
Still not being able to figure out why I'm getting this error.
My code is as follow:-

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        running = False  # Global flag

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        strt = tk.Button(self, text="Start Scan", command=self.start)
        stp = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop)

        button.pack()       
        strt.pack()
        stp.pack()
        self.after(1000, self.scann)  # After 1 second, call scanning

    def scann(self):
        if running:
          sub.call(['./runfocus'], shell=True)

        self.after(1000, self.scann)

    def start(self):
        """Enable scanning by setting the global flag to True."""
        global running
        running = True

    def stop(self):
        """Stop scanning by setting the global flag to False."""
        global running
        running = False
```

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: looks like a indentation issue, looking at above code

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Correct your indentation, as it stands the `scann` function is not part of the class (which would explain the error).  We can't tell if that's a copy n'paste issue or your code is really like that.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a global here? You have a class, use it to hold state information. BTW, in `__init__`, that `running` is a local name, so doing `running = False` there doesn't affect the global `running`.

Comment: @PM2Ring we have to see if he intended that :/

Comment: Pardon me. 
I think it got messed up while posting.

Comment: @NoorAliJafri True, although the `self` args are a good indication that he didn't. ;) But he's fixed it now,

Comment: Here I want to run a bash script by pressing the start button and want to stop the script by pressing stop. 
I put scann function or self.after to run the script continuously till the user doesn't press the stop button.

Comment: please also share the code where you are calling this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the `AttributeError: PageOne instance has no attribute 'scann' error`, but your script has other issues, due to that `running` flag. You should avoid using modifiable globals, and when you've already got a class, there's absolutely no need to use a separate global. Just create an attribute as the flag.

Here's a runnable repaired version of your code. I've replaced the `sub.call(['./runfocus'], shell=True)` call with a simple `print` call so that we can see that `start` and `stop` behave correctly.

```
import tkinter as tk

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.running = False

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        strt = tk.Button(self, text="Start Scan", command=self.start)
        stp = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop)

        button.pack()
        strt.pack()
        stp.pack()
        self.after(1000, self.scann)  # After 1 second, call scanning

    def scann(self):
        if self.running:
            #sub.call(['./runfocus'], shell=True)
            print("calling runfocus")

        self.after(1000, self.scann)

    def start(self):
        """Enable scanning by setting the flag to True."""
        self.running = True

    def stop(self):
        """Stop scanning by setting the flag to False."""
        self.running = False


root = tk.Tk()
frame = PageOne(root, root)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```